# Limit without L'Hopital $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\pi - 4\arctan{1\over 1+x}}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Evaluate the limit: 
>   $$
> \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\pi - 4\arctan{1\over 1+x}}{x}
> $$

I've been able to show the limit is equal to $2$ using L'Hopital's rule. After finding the derivative of the nominator the limits simply becomes:
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{4}{x^2 + 2x+2} = 2
$$

I'm looking for a way to find the limit **without involving derivatives**, but rather using some elementary methods. I've also played around with the identities involving $\arctan x$ but didn't find anything suitable.

Could someone please suggest a method to solve that problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $\dfrac\pi4-\arctan\dfrac1{1+x}=y$

$\dfrac1{1+x}=\tan\left(\dfrac\pi4-y\right)=\dfrac{1-\tan y}{1+\tan y}$

$x=?$

Comment: This one is the most elegant so far. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You may use two facts:

- $\arctan a - \arctan b = \arctan \frac{a-b}{1+ab}$
- $\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\arctan y}{y} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t}{\tan t} = 1$

\begin{eqnarray*}\frac{\pi - 4\arctan{1\over 1+x}}{x}
& = & 4\cdot \frac{\frac{\pi}{4}
 - \arctan\frac{1}{1+x}}{x}\\
& = & 4\cdot  \frac{\arctan \frac{1-\frac{1}{1+x}}{1+\frac{1}{1+x}}}{x} \\
& = & 4\cdot \frac{\arctan \frac{x}{x+2}}{\frac{x}{x+2}\cdot (x+2)}  \\
& \stackrel{x \to 0}{\longrightarrow} &\frac{4}{2} = 2
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Nice approach. Thank you! Definitely (+1)

Comment: You are welcome and thank you. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite as
$$
-4\frac{\arctan(1/(1+x))-\pi/4}{x}
$$
then it is of the form: $-4\,(f(x)-f(0))/(x-0)$ with $f(x)=\arctan(1/(1+x))$ which by definition tends to $-4\,f'(0)=2$

Comment: To my mind, your answer actually shows that using Hospital's rule is circular, as the original limit to evaluate is a derivative. On the other hand, the original question explicitly asked for no derivatives at all...